Are electrostatics conditions still valid in Current carrying conductors?
Question 1: How is steady Electric field generated inside a conductor ?
Question 2: Why do we say that electrostatic conditions still hold in a current carrying conductor(drift speed is small obviously), but the “charges are in motion” and “ Field is non zero” ;  both the phenomena are never valid in Electrostatics conditions
I am in grade 9, have interest in Physics

If you want to ping a specific user, please do so in chat.

Please specify sources of your understanding or any mention of topic you read, perhaps, try mentioning your understanding, FYI, Do you know electric fields inside current carrying wires is due to specific configuration(Gradient) of surface charges due to potential difference applied?

But how do we say electrostatic conditions are still valid when there is field inside a conductor matrix now ..

@John Rennie Please Help

@Kampann You can't tag a user in a post they didn't answer or comment in. You need to do so through chat

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but I will try to answer as best as I can. When we talk about electrostatics we are generally talking about working with the theory of electricity and magnetism with a fixed charge distribution and current distribution. So the charge and current at a point are not changing. Note that this allows us to have moving charge (current) and still satisfy every requirement. This is because if I have charge at a point and I have current flowing through it if as much charge enters as leaves that point after an arbitrary time period then the charge at that point will stay the same (satisfying our electrostatic conditions).
In regard to your question about non-zero field in a conductor with electrostatics I'm not sure I understand the question. In electrostatics a perfect conductor will have 0 field inside of it as if it did the field would accelerate charges and change currents. If you are talking about the process that creates the current in the conductor, that process is not electrostatic, but once the current has reached its final value our system will be electrostatic. I hope this helps.

But after current has attained steady state, you say it is electrostatic condition but why is field not zero inside
